# Note: Undefined Offset: 2

Tags: php, exception, undefined, offset

The answers I found for this exception were not very helpful. Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks

```
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $cartcount; $x++)
    {
      $innerarray = $cart[$x];              //this is the exception-producing line
      $quantity = $innerarray['quantity'];
      $title = $innerarray['articleTitle'];
      $articlenumber = $innerarray['articleNumber'];

      $outputQNT[] = $innerarray['quantity'];

      $outputTITLE[] = $innerarray['articleTitle'];

      $outputATNBR[] = $innerarray['articleNumber'];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array start form zero & end with total array length-1.
so in for loop:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <$cartcount; $x++){}
```

if $cartcount = 2 then array index are [0,1]

If still there is problem then use :

```
array_values($cartcount)
```

It will return array with proper indexing